# Как прописать 301 редирект для страниц?

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Помогите прописать 301 редирект в .htaccess. Нужно все страницы оканчивающиеся на .htm перенаправить на точно такой же урл, но с окончанием .html

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.htm [NC]
```

Первая строка по зависимости!